# How to handle separate state for each browser tab in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

We are opening new window tab which contains the userList based on the selected userId from a list. I open the new window like this:

```
this.props.getVisitDetails(this.props.userId)
var win = window.open('./requisition','_blank');
win.onload = function() { this.document.title = windowTittle; }
win.focus();
this.state.oldWindow.push(win);
```

Here I am getting `userId` from the Redux store. The problem is that if I am opening more than one window tab then `userId` on every window tab will have the same `userId` and when you will click refresh then all window tabs will have the same data. So my question is **how can I maintain a separate state for each window tab?**

Note: all browser tab all sharing same stored state that we saved using createstore method,so in my case visitid will be updated on every row click which will open browser's new tab. This is how the data is "shared"

Comment: As much I understand, you are opening a new browser tab. I don't think two tabs can share/have same state. Infact, browser tabs don't share data.

Comment: Yes all browser tab all sharing same stored state that we saved using createstore method,so in my case visitid will be updated on every row click which will open browser's  new tab.

Comment: I dont think that is possible. Redux state cant be shared across browser tabs

Comment: You can download redux debugger for crome and check

Comment: You don't have explicit control over browser tabs. You can however manipulate your URL so that your component would load different data accordingly.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 First, is his observation correct? Can you share data from one tab to other ?

Comment: My question is simple,Is all browser tab maintain the same redux store or for each tab it maintain separate redux store? As I observed, all tab in browser maintaining the same redux store.

Comment: Create random UUID for each tab, then save the root of the store under that. So you essentially store a different copy of the store for each tab.

Answer (score 2):

Your store is not shared across multiple tabs, So every time you open new tab your whole application gets loaded again along with initialization of fresh store.
So, In your case simple solution will be to open new tab with URL containing userId as query param`(window.open('./requisition?userId=${userId}','_blank');)`. Such that you will be able to maintain separate userId in different browser tabs.